# How to commit folders, files from a local repository to a central repository along with the change history?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I copied a solution from the repository and pasted in a different location. There I created a local repository. Now, it's time to commit back all my changes to the central repository.

The easiest way would be to copy the solution to the folder that is being tracked by SVN, so that when I commit, that solution will be committed also to the repository. However, I don't think the history of all the changes will be committed back.

So how to commit the solution along with the changes history?